# A line crossing root-node in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am facing a little problem. I have a line crossing a root-node.. How to fix it ?

```
\tikzset{
        basic/.style  = {draw, text width=1.5cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
        root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin, align=center,
            fill=green!60, text width=13cm},
        level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=4pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60,
            text width=8em},
        level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=8em, align=center}
    }
    \hspace*{0cm}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=70mm},
        edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
        >=latex]

        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]

        \node[root] (c1) {AAAAA};

        \node [below of = c1, xshift=-4cm, yshift=0cm] (c11) {S};
        \node [below of = c11] (c12) {D};
        \node [below of = c12] (c13) {R};

        \node [below of = c1, xshift=4cm, yshift=.15cm] (c14) {W};
        \node [below of = c14, yshift=-0.5cm] (c15) {K};
        \node [below of = c15, yshift=-0.5cm] (c16) {M};
        \end{scope}

        \foreach \value in {1,2,3}
        \draw[->] (c1.120) |- (c1\value.east);

        \foreach \value in {4,5,6}
        \draw[->] (c1.270) |- (c1\value.west);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: change `c1.120` to `c1.250`

Comment: Please always post a complete small document rather than a code fragment, especially when your question depends on specialist packages and libraries. That ensures your question is useful to others and makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax `c1.120` means a point at intersection of `c1` node's border and a line with angle 120 degrees from node's center. In your case this point is on top border and `\draw[->] (c1.120) |- (c1\value.east);` crosses the node. If you want to respect this syntax, you just need to select an angle which places starting point on bottom border, like `c1.250`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] (c1) {};

\node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, below left= 0.5cm and 0.5cm of c1] (c2) {};

\draw (c1.center) -- (120:2cm);
\draw (c1.center) -- (0:2cm);
\draw (0:1.5cm) arc [start angle=0, end angle=120, radius=1.5cm] node[midway, above right] {$120^\circ$};
\draw[fill=red] (c1.120) circle (2pt);
\draw (c1.120) |- (c2);

\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] (c1) {};
\node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, below left= 0.5cm and 0.5cm of c1] (c2) {};
\draw (c1.center) -- (250:2cm);
\draw (c1.center) -- (0:2cm);
\draw (0:1.5cm) arc [start angle=0, end angle=250, radius=1.5cm] node[midway, above left] {$250^\circ$};
\draw[fill=red] (c1.250) circle (2pt);
\draw (c1.250) |- (c2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```